# Generated repository within a repository

Tags: git, github

## What I'm trying to do

Here's my github repository:

https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial

Inside that repository is a PowerShell script: [LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1](https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial/blob/main/LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1)

That script generates a new git repository, named `LinkAggregator`.

Ideally, I'd like to keep that generated repository inside the [LinkAggregatorTutorial](https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial) repository.

## The issue

The issue is, I would imagine that this is an unusual arrangement; i.e. having a repository inside another repository.

I did a little bit of research on this topic and found git *submodules*. However, at first glance, my use case doesn't seem to be exactly the right target for submodules. The generated git repository (LinkAggregator) isn't a dependency of the parent repository (LinkAggregatorTutorial).

So my question is, is there a good way to set this up?

## Options

To summarize, my current options are:

1. Just put `LinkAggregator` inside `LinkAggregatorTutorial` and it'll just work.
2. Make `LinkAggregator` a submodule of `LinkAggregatorTutorial`
3. Don't try to keep `LinkAggregator` inside `LinkAggregatorTutorial`. Simply host it in another repository on github. (Although, then I seem to run into the same issue there. Moreover, `LinkAggregator` can't really be a top-level standalone repository since it is generated from scratch every so often.)
4. Generate `LinkAggregator` inside `LinkAggregatorTutorial` but then remove the `LinkAggregator/.git` directory, rendering it just a normal folder with files in it as opposed to a full on git repository. The drawback is, it's no longer a repository, but I may be able to live with that. The important thing is that the user can see the generated project. If the user generates the project on their system, they'll of course still get the full git repository.
5. Have `LinkAggregatorTutorial/.gitignore` include `LinkAggregator/.git`. This way, locally, `LinkAggregator` is still a git repository. But as far as github is concerned, it's just a regular folder.
6. Some other arrangement...

## More context

A little more context:

- [LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1](https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial/blob/main/LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1) is a PowerShell script that generates the `LinkAggregator` repository (it's an ASP.NET Core project).
- Every once in a while, I'll be updating [LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1](https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial/blob/main/LinkAggregatorTutorial.ps1) and then regenerating the `LinkAggregator` repository. Thus, I won't be making little incremental updates to `LinkAggregator` (as is normally done with a git repository). It's automatically generated and thus, a completely new repository will be generated from time to time. It's this repository that I'd like to have inside `LinkAggregatorTutorial`.
- [LinkAggregatorTutorial.md](https://github.com/dharmatech/LinkAggregatorTutorial/blob/main/LinkAggregatorTutorial.md) is the rendered version of tutorial. The reader is meant to go through that manually. However, then can, if they choose, run the tutorial to generate the final project, just to test if the steps work on their system. I'd like to, of course, also provide the generated project on github.

## Update

Upon writing all this out, it seems like option 4 is a practical approach and I'm leaning towards it. But, I figured I'd leave this question up to see if a git wizard has any thoughts or suggestions on this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If there's some dependency between the two repos, you should use submodules.

But you wrote that the generated git repository isn't a dependency of the parent repository. So in this case, one shouldn't reside inside the other. They should be two completely separate repos.

Comment: Hey Slavik. Yeah, I agree that submodules aren't appropriate here. I'm leaning towards keeping the generated project inside the main repository, but not having it be repository. Just a normal project directory.